# How to drag UIView into the table header

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

I am reading the Book: **Beginning iOS 5 development.**
One of it example is to drag the UIView into the table header of UITableView

I have tried many times, no matter how I drag my UIView above the UITableView, the UIView will not fit the table header. It just looks like a big rectangle.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my problem.
The answer is a little bit tricky, I cannot see the effect as same as the book shown, may be the interface builder has change a little bit. I can only see **a small blue line** on top of the table.

**The view cannot be dragged directly into the table header.**

1. Drag the UIView into the view.
2. Drag the view above the table/ drag it inside the table in the
   objects list at the left.
3. Resize the view to the height of the table header

**Be aware of the object hierarchy.**

[image: first step]
[image: second step]
[image: third step]

Answer (score 1):

When you drag the view just under "Table View" in the list (Placeholders, Objects) it should be inserted there.

Answer (score 1):

Do One thing,Select your table in the nib and then go to its properties.
Go to size inspector in the nib,there select table view size
in that you need to change section height, say you make it 80 Pixels, Now you can place your view there and make its height 80 as well.
And change your view's frame as well to properly position it over your table view header.
That you can also do from your nib
Hope it will help you.

Thanks
Sabby